# Response CreateAPIView DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want response for `CreateAPIView` like this return

```
Response(
            {
                'status': status_code.HTTP_200_OK,
                'message': 'Testimonials fetched',
                'data': serializer.data
             },)
```

But i dont know which function will be best to use inside `AddAPIView` to get response like above

```
class AddAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Masjid.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MasjidAddSerialzer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Override the **`create()`** method of the **`AddAPIView`** view class

```
class AddAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
        queryset = Masjid.objects.all()
        serializer_class = serializers.MasjidAddSerialzer
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({
            'status': 200,
            'message': 'Testimonials fetched',
            'data': response.data
        })
```

Comment: What's the purpose of using `queryset = Masjid.objects.all()` in `CreateAPIView`?

Comment: a `queryset` attribute or `get_queryset()` method doesn't have any effect in  ***`generics.CreateAPIView`*** class, unless we use them explicitly. In this post, It was actually c&p from the OP @haccks

Comment: Imagine a case where this query will load millions of records. It is better not to use it in CreateAPIView unless necessary for sure.

Comment: No, that won't happen, because [the Django QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)